# Electron.js + React.js + context isolation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I designed a simple Electron.js APP with React.js.
Here there is my package.json

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^20.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
```

Now i'm trying to increase security by adding context-isolation

```js
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: "#ccc",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
```

Uasually I use IPC https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc,
but I still dont know ho to manage the imports in "main world" required by React.js.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```